# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ersion: OpenPGP.js v3' getting this error while installing create-react-app and aborting

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ersion: OpenPGP.js v3' getting this error while installing create-react-app and aborting[image]

Comment: which version of node and npm are you using ?

Comment: Have you tried this `npx create-react-app my-app`? Ref - https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: I have tried with npx create-react-app my-app also

Comment: I'm using node - 8.16 and npm 6.9

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the answers in this question helped me.

source issue: [Error installing reactjs: Error unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133892/error-installing-reactjs-error-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near)

I just needed to run the following command

npm cache clean --force