# Error installing reactjs: Error unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, installation, failed-installation

I tried installing reactjs via node using two different commands in the terminal using 1) `npx create-react-app my-app` and 2) `npx create-react-app app`

But both yielded the same error shown below:

> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
>
> Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '....1","object-hash":"^1'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-12T03_53_37_836Z-debug.log
>
> Aborting installation.
>
> npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom
>   react-scripts cra-template has failed.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling node and also trying to install different older versions of reactjs but still got the same error. Also, I have tried clearing the node cache and then verifying it again via `npm cache clear --force` and then `npm cache verify` but still have not had any luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The more detailed log shows this at the bottom:

> 203 silly saveTree `-- react@16.12.0
>
> 204 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while
>   parsing near '....1","object-hash":"^1'
>
> 204 verbose stack at JSON.parse ()
>
> 204 verbose stack at parseJson (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
>
> 204 verbose stack at C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
>
> 204 verbose stack at processTicksAndRejections
>   (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>
> 205 verbose cwd C:\Users\David\Desktop\React\my-app
>
> 206 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
>
> 207 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save"
>   "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom"
>   "react-scripts" "cra-template"
>
> 208 verbose node v13.8.0
>
> 209 verbose npm v6.13.6
>
> 210 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '....1","object-hash":"^1'
>
> 211 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Please try to update your nodejs and then start a fresh.

Comment: I tried updating nodejs but still get the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Installing yarn using node package manager fixed the issue for me. Open command prompt and enter:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Comment: Brilliant! I totally forgot yarn and wasted my day with npm.

Comment: yeah its working with yarn , had lot of problem with npm

Answer (score 32):

Try running this in your terminal:

`npm cache clean --force`

And redo the thing you are doing

Comment: cannot believe I spent several hours fighting npm before I found this. I actually thought something was wrong with my project smh.

Comment: yeah i spent 2 days figuring this

Comment: Gosh. Just when we all thought `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` was good enough...

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then try again to create your app (here when creating a react app) or install what you were about to install.

```
create-react-app myproject
```

(creating react app)[same npm problem that can occur in different operation]

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

(installing angular cli (or installing anything else))

It will work.

## explanation:

That's a problem related to npm, it's about the cache that get corrupt. Even though in newer versions of npm they implemented self healing, which normally guarantee no corruption, but it seem it's not that efficient. 
[image]
Forcing clean cache resolve the problem.

The error happen when parsing one of the cache files, which have a json format. The cache is found at ~/.npm/_cacache (in linux) and  %AppData%/npm-cache (windows). For my current npm version and when i checked, there was three directories.
[image]

if you check the first or the second, the structure is as follow
[image]

And each cache file have a json format (and that what get parsed)
[image]

Here a good link from the doc: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

[Update] Also if it happen that this didn't solve it, you may check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191315/7668448 it show how you can change the npm registry, that can be helpful. Check and see.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but 
`npm cache clean --force`  didn't work for me.

What I did was
CLEAN MY PC

using my cleaner(CCleaner) and npm install work now. I did it because the problem appears after I uninstall my node.js because I want to install nvm-windows on my PC (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-windows), but after I did it I think some files and folders was leave behind making a conflict after I install node using nvm thus npm install do not work. So I thought cleaning my pc would solve the problem and it did.

These are just my thoughts. Hope to help someone.

Comment: would you try yarn in the place of npm

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using:

npm cache clean --force
:/

Answer (score 0):

`sudo npm install -g create-react-app` worked for me

Comment: This should be in the comment section.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal Not necessarily. Even if it's very short, it still answers the question.

Comment: Agree with you. @DonaldDuck

Answer (score 0):

It occurs due to hard caching in Yarn. I resolved the issue by deleting the node_modules folder and ran again

```
yarn install
```

which generated a new node_modules folder and the issue was resolved.