# I am having an error while installing Create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I want to get started with React.js and I am following their official documentation that states to use - `npx create-react-app my-app` to install the app, but I am getting the error below every time. Please help

[image]

Comment: what do the contents of that log file say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following ways to resolve the error -

1. Delete everything from `C:\Users\your_pc_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
2. This could be a local caching issue. Try the command `npm cache clean --force` using administrator mode in your terminal and then try again with the same command - `npx create-react-app my-app`.
3. If the above command doesn't work, try the same command or another similiar command - `npm cache clear --force` and then `npm install` after that. After this, you can run the commands to setup your react project and see if it works.

These were the point I have referred online from people who faced a similar issue. Try to see if any of the above steps resolve your issue.

I have aggregated the working solutions but if this still doesn't solve your problem, you could refer the links mentioning a similar problem -

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7261
- [Installing create-react-app gives npm ERR! shasum check failed and npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...mojOzGIEI2rg0m24Yb5Oq'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189096/installing-create-react-app-gives-npm-err-shasum-check-failed-and-npm-err-unex/50191315#50191315)
- [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)
- [Error installing reactjs: Error unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133892/error-installing-reactjs-error-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near)