# When I create React app It's not creating

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, error-handling, tags

I am beginner in react js

I'm Create react app  it's give me a error I am trying to do all the things

cmd to create app

```
npx create-react-app my-app or npx create-react-app@latest your-app-name --use-npm
```

error

```
npx create-react-app my-reactchat-app
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dp312\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-25T22_46_04_461Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

I'm try to do this cmd in both mode *administrator mode* also

```
npm cache clean --force
```

when run this cmd

```
npm create-react-app my-app
```

it's give me error like this

```
    Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\dp312\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.15 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

try to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061748/i-am-having-an-error-while-installing-create-react-app)  also but still error not soul

how to solve this error ?

anyone can help me

Comment: can you show the log output? (`C:\Users\dp312\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-25T22_46_04_461Z-debug.log`)

Comment: yes it's so many line's in log output

Comment: Looks like you’re using an older version of NPM. Try upgrading it with `sudo npm install -g npm`.

Answer (score 0):

Define the node engines config in package.json
Also, check your node version keep it latest.
Check if you're running the app from inside of your app folder.

Comment: node -v v14.18.1 || I'm just create 1 time app and my folder is empty

Comment: https://sebhastian.com/npm-err-cb-never-called/
try all the possible solutions from here

Comment: I'm try all those think but still can't create app